# Response not returing properly

Tags: angular, lumen

When I make the api call i get back a 200 but the response returns html and the error i get in the console is Http failure during parsing for http://moviereview.test/moviereview/api/v1/public/login?email=conor@testing.com&password=name" the response is in json format can someone tell why this is happening also I know its bad pratice to post password in the url Im just tring to get the response working properly and then addressing any security issues when I run it in postman it returns it as a JSON

```js
/*Login Component*/
onSubmit() {
  this.api.login(this.user.email, this.user.password).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.user = data;
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    });
 }
}
/*Login Service*/
  login(email: string, password: string) {
                const httpOptions = {
                  headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
                  })
                };
                return this.http.post<any>(this.env.LOCAL_ENDPOINT + '/login?email=' + email + '&password=' + password, httpOptions);
            }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a bit of the actual response from the Network tab of your developer tools? It looks like JSON is not being returned but an HTML error page. Looking at the error, the `text` portion it looks to be HTML not JSON.

Comment: Updated with html response

Comment: This is all that shows up in the response tab

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the HttpOptions as the body in the request. The second parameter of the post method on the http client is the request body. For a login you should be using a post method and pass the email and password in the request body as shown below:

```
/*Login Service*/
login(email: string, password: string) {
            const requestBody = {
                email: email,
                password: password
            };
            const httpOptions = {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type':  'application/json'
              })
            };
            return this.http.post<any>(this.env.LOCAL_ENDPOINT + '/login', requestBody, httpOptions);
        }
```

Comment: This will be an issue with the endpoint then as that http request is valid. Does your endpoint expect a get request or a post request?

Comment: Its expecting a post request when I run the query in postman it returns the response with the correct data

Comment: I can see your issue. You're sending a your post request with query parameters. This is strange for a post request in most situations (including this one). You need to change your server to take email and password from the request body not the request query parameters.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help it was the url that the api was pointing at in the web application it worked with postman because the url was right but it didnt work in angular because the url was pointing at the wrong place thats why it would return html and Ive switched the query params over to use a payload